# is there a way to copy the loaded ivy jars to the filesystem in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, filesystems, ivy

In Eclipse - I can copy the jars loaded on the classpath for a project to a directory on the file system.

When the jars are loaded into the project using ivy - I can't do this.

My question is - **is there a way to copy the loaded ivy jars to the filesystem in eclipse?**

**Assumptions:**

- Windows 7
- Eclipse Kepler SR 1
- Ivy 2.3.0Final

**Clarification**

I need just the project jars - I have thousands of jars in my ivy repository.

Comment: The jars are located in  ~\.ivy2\, or you need to filter the project jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the ivy [retrieve task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html)?

For example the following will put your ivy dependencies into a local "lib" directory:

```
<ivy:retrieve 
     pattern="lib/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"
     conf="runtime"/>
```

The "conf" attribute is optional, used if you want to choose a particular group of dependencies.